# Flutter: How to run a background task which will listen to a queue for data?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I want to create a background function in flutter which listens to a queue continuously and whenever data available in the queue it gets the data in a FIFO manner and do some work like http call with the data?

Where should I begin. I think I can use isolates, but maintaining the queue is what confuses me as it doesn't have a shared memory.

Comment: I would think `Provider` package is the solution you're looking for : https://pub.dev/packages/provider . It helps to share in different place a common and single source data provider

Comment: where does your input data come from?

Comment: I'm creating a chat application, so whenever the user send some message Im planning to put them on a queue (for offline cases also) and when the background runner found any item on queue it takes it and call the http method if network available or wait if network not there

Comment: check https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Comment: @pskink The backend is written in node so no firebase other than for push notifications.